# Where does this max-width (@media) CSS come from?

Tags: mobile, screen, css

There are 2 pages, that some part of the code is repeated, to this part of code, I apply this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sliderContent {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

When I check one page on an iPhone, it loads this CSS, but the other does not use this style.

I have added an alert with the screen size in both pages, and both have the same width.

Do you know where the `max-width` is taken? that could be making the difference between the two pages?

Can the HTML somehow affect the size of the `min-width`?

Comment: Post your html or a sample of it including your doctype declaration, if any, for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max width is the width of the viewport in css pixels. What that declaration is saying is that when the viewport is less than 767px width, apply the .sliderContent style.

The reason it applys to the iPhone is that the reported width is less than 767px. If you were to open the page in question in a newer browser (IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, etc), and resize the window below 767px you'll see the same result.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/css-length-explained/

Comment: Thanks!

In iphone, both pages shound not have the same viewport? why one should have a viewport less than 767px and the other dont?

Comment: Are different pages displaying differently on the iPhone. If so check for the viewport declaration in the body meta tags.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`
See here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag